# Jquery javascript associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to create an associative javascript/jquery array of this php structure:

```
$array = array(
    'index' => array(
        'subindex' => 'default',
        'subindex' => 'default'                                         
    ),
    'index2' => array(
        'subindex2' => 'default',
        'subindex2' => 'default'                                            
    )
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Javascript does not have associative arrays.  It has objects, which can have properties accessible like this: `obj['propName']`, which kind of makes it look like an associative array....but it's not really an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = {
  'index': {
    'subindex1': 'default',
    'subindex2': 'default'
  },
  'index2': {
    'subindex1': 'default',
    'subindex2': 'default'
  }
};
```

Comment: it's called a hash or object in JS, btw

Answer (score 4):

[JSON Encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

`echo json_encode($array);`

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var anArray = [
                    {"index":[
                    {"subindex":"default"},
                    {"subindex":"default"}
                    ]},
                    {"index2":[
                    {"subindex":"default"},
                    {"subindex2":"default"}
                    ]}
                ];
</script>
```